# Is the generalized Kummer threefold rational in characteristics 3?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, birational-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, minimal-model-program

Let $E_i\!: y_i^2 = x_i^3 - x_i$, $i = 1, 2, 3$ be three copies of the supersingular elliptic curve in characteristics $3$. Consider on $E_i$ the following automorphism of order $3$: 
$$
\sigma(x_i,y_i) = (x_i+1,y_i).
$$

It is obvious that the generalized Kummer surface 
$$E_1\!\times\! E_2/(\sigma,\sigma)\!: \ y_1^2 - y_2^2 = t^3-t$$ (where $t = x_1-x_2$) is rational, because there is a natural conic bundle structure with respect to the variable $t$.

Consider the generalized Kummer threefold
$$E_1\!\times\! E_2 \!\times\! E_3/(\sigma,\sigma,\sigma)\!: 
\begin{cases}
y_1^2 - y_2^2 = t^3-t,\\
y_1^2 - y_3^2 = s^3-s,
\end{cases}$$
where $t = x_1-x_2$, $s = x_1-x_3$. 
Is this threefold also rational? For example, is there any bundle structure?